# How to set up email account on Outlook for an email with domain on gmail?

Tags: email, dns, outlook, gmail, installation

My company's email domain is at gmail, my email address is myname@companyname.com but I access it on www.gmail.com. I tried to set up the email on outlook but it asks me for ISP password, I entered my email password but it didn't work.

How can I set up account for this email on outlook ?

Comment: Offtopic. Ask your system administrator for details.

Comment: Where is the correct forum to ask this question ?

Comment: Ask at a general user focused forum like http://forums.cnet.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the detailed steps here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/174837/how-to-add-your-gmail-account-to-outlook-2013-using-imap/